# app.UseDefaultFiles in Kestrel not doing anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel

I have this in a Startup.cs file for a small project for a webserver hosting static files with Kestrel:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("config.json");
        var config = configBuilder.Build();

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
           .AddRedirectToHttps();

        app.UseRewriter(options);

        DefaultFilesOptions defoptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(defoptions);


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"static")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("")
        });

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(config.GetSection(key: "Logging"));
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't try to load an index.html or anything. If I access it manually, it does indeed work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the path to your index.html file - is it under wwwroot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally your `index.html` should be under the web root path (`wwwroot`), however, if your file is under `ContentRootPath\static` (as it appears to be), you will need to change your code to specify the `DefaultFilesOptions.FileProvider` as follows:

```
PhysicalFileProvider fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"static"));
DefaultFilesOptions defoptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
defoptions.FileProvider = fileProvider;
defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
app.UseDefaultFiles(defoptions);

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = new PathString("")
});
```

*Note:* you are probably better off using `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` (`env.ContentRootPath`) rather than `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` on the first line (just in case you want to change the content root in your `WebHostBuilder` at some point).

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. Didn't figure out I had to use FileProvider with DefaultFilesOptions as well  (-_-)

Comment: This is, of course, straight out of the documentation. And using either this example, or the documentation example, I cannot get this to work on a WebAPI Core 2.1 project.

Answer (score 4):

Kudos to CalC for his insight, which got me closer to the answer for asp.net core 2.2. Here's what I ended up needing to do to serve a default document outside of the main web server root in Azure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){...

// content is physically stored at /site/abc on an Azure Web App, not /site/wwwroot/abc
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "abc");
PhysicalFileProvider fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path); 

DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions 
    {
        FileProvider = fileProvider, 
        RequestPath = "/ABC",
    }; 
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                   {
                       FileProvider = fileProvider,
                       RequestPath = "/ABC"
                   });
}
```

The key was using matching RequestPath and FileProvider values